# How to check cookie enable in android opera browser by js

Tags: android, jquery

I am trying to check weather the cookies are enabled or not in Opera (Android) Browser. The below code working fine in default browser, but not in Opera.

```
var cookieEnabled = (navigator.cookieEnabled) ? true : false;     
if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled == "undefined" && !cookieEnabled)
    { 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled = (document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie") != -1) ? true : false;
    }
    if(cookieEnabled==true){
        jQuery('#androidpopup').modal('show');
    }
```

I am using this code on page load. Guide me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: How about the idea to create a cookie and and then read the same? If returns null or undefined, cokkies are not enabled.

Comment: I am using the same but it is not returning null in opera if cookies are disable

Comment: And what is the return value? You have to create a simple name,value pair.